# How do I do a 'math' spam check using react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm trying to combat spam emails within my reactJs project. I'm using react-hook-form as the form provider. I'd like to present a user with a simple math equation and use that to validate the form. If the math doesn't add up, the form can't be submitted. The form is rather lengthy, so here's a slimmed-down version only focusing on that input:

```
function Contact_ContactForm_Form() {
  const [spamCheck, setInput] = useState({
    num1: generateRandomIntegerInRange(0, 10), 
    num2: generateRandomIntegerInRange(0, 10),
  })
  const spamCheckAnswer = useMemo(
    () => parseInt(spamCheck.num1) + parseInt(spamCheck.num2), [spamCheck],
  )
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset, formState: { errors }} = useForm()
  const onSubmit = (data) => { reset() }
  return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} >
          <input
            type='email'
            {...register('email', {
              required: { message: 'Please enter your email.', value: true },
              minLength: { message: "c'mon that's not your email", value: 4 },
              pattern: {
                value:
                  /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
                message: 'Invalid email address',
              },})}
          />
          <input
            type='number'
            placeholder={`${spamCheck.num1} + ${spamCheck.num2}`}
            {...register('spamCheck', {
              required: {
                message: "Please prove that you're human and have passed fourth grade",
                value: true,
              },
              value: {
                value: spamCheckAnswer,
                message:
                  "Incorrect math. Please prove that you're human and have passed fourth grade",
              },
            })}
          />
            <input type='submit' />
            {errors.email && <div>{errors.email.message}</div>}
            {errors.spamCheck && <div >{errors.spamCheck.message}</div>}
        </form>
  )}
export default Contact_ContactForm_Form
```

Comment: it's been quite a few years since those stopped being reliable (AI made bots much, much better), is something like invisible recaptcha not an option?

Comment: Oh, I'm sure it is, but I couldn't figure out how to integrate that either

Comment: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible is pretty usable - just put the `execute` in your component instead and you're off to the races.